# Basic property of differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

can someone tell me if the following property is true?

If $f:]a,b[\rightarrow{]0,\infty[}$ is a continuous function then a maximal solution of the differential equation : $x'=f(x)$ which is defined in $]\alpha,\omega[$ is an homeomorphism between $]\alpha,\omega[$ and $]a,b[$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can answer that by exploring the separation-of-variables formula. Let $g$ be an integral of $g'(x)=f(x)^{-1}$ with $g(x_0)=t_0$. $g$ is monotonous growing, so $α=\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ and $ω=\lim_{x\to b}g(x)$ can be defined, if infinite limits are included.

Now explore what $g$ tells you about the soluton of the initial value problem $x(t_0)=x_0$.

Comment: Why do you know that there exists $f^{-1}$?

Comment: This is $f(x)^{-1}=1/f(x)$, not the inverse function. You need to show that $g$ can be inverted.

Comment: Ok. Other question: Why can you use saparated variables?

Comment: Because $f(x)\ne 0$ for $x\in]a,b[$. And $f$ is only a function of $x$.

Comment: But the solution $x$ is function of $t$ then $f=f(x(t))$

Comment: Yes, and? $\frac{d}{dt}g(x(t))=g'(x(t))\dot x(t)=(1/f(x(t)))\cdot f(x(t))=1$ so that $g(x(t))=t$ characterizes $g$ as inverse function of $x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87091/discussion-between-mathlife-and-lutzl).